Replacing DVD styler files when changing platforms
I had a DVD Styler file that I created on Windows, with paths starting with C:\Users\username\. I am now on Linux and want to change them to /home/username/. I searched online but couldn't find an immediate solution. I also right-clicked on a video item and tried adding with the + button, but it looks for a subtitle or audio file, not a video file.
How can I change all filepaths on the DVD Styler after changing platform?

A DVD Styler file is simply an XML file, so you can replace the files in your favorite text editor. For example, replace this text on windows:
C:\Users\username

with this text on Linux:
/home/username

If changing from Windows to Unix (macOS or Linux), also replace backward slashes, \, with forward slashes / elsewhere in the file.
Note: you can also use relative paths, e.g. assets/  for an image file in the assets directory sibling to the DVD Styler file, or ../ for one directory above.
